# Bootstrap carousel indicators are square; I want them round

Tags: html, css

I have just successfully set up a 3-image carousel on my site using Bootstrap. This is what it looks like:

[image]

If you notice, the indicators are square and I want them to be round! All the tutorials I have followed thus far seem to get it right; I have never seen anyone else's carousel with square indicators. Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- Carousel start -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="bootstrap/img/home-page-banner.jpg"/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Heading One</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Sign up!</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="bootstrap/img/home-page-banner.jpg"/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Heading One</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Sign up!</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="bootstrap/img/home-page-banner.jpg"/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Heading One</h1>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Sign up!</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- Carousel end -->
```

What do you think I am going wrong with here? Is there any class I should be using with the `carousel-indicators` `<ol>` that I am not aware of yet?

P.s.: I have already tried `.carousel-indicators { border-radius: 100%;}` with no success.

Comment: We'll need to see a complete code example to be able to reproduce the problem. You probably have CSS of your own that's causing this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add `border-radius`:

```
.carousel-indicators > li {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Note that you have to target the `li` tags within the `carousel-indicators` class and also do `50%` not `100%`.

So you don't have to use `!important` to override the default border-radius:

```
#myCarousel-indicators > li {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

<ol id="myCarousel-indicators" class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
```

Comment: @AmitSchandillia Are you sure you wrote it exactly like this? Because you didn't in your question snippet. Also check the console to see if the border-radius gets overridden by another selector or something.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia Add your css for the indicators so it's easier to debug.

Comment: The code in question was tried before your post. It was lifted off another post on SO. But I tried your code as well and it didn't change anything.

Comment: By default, Bootstrap adds a `border-radius: 10px;` to `.carousel-indicators li { ... }`, you probably have a theme that sets that to `0`. Use the dev tool to inspect the element.

Comment: I would add the CSS to the question as well if I had one. I mean I haven't overridden any defaults on the classes in question except for the two attempts on the carousel-indicators class as already explained.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia Check console to see if there is a border-radius already set for the list items

Comment: OK, I just added !important to your code and it worked! But is there a more elegant way? Kinda wary of `important`, dunno why.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia You can add an ID to the ol element and then do perform the same code, and it will work without important

Comment: @AmitSchandillia "But is there a more elegant way?" Yes. Please learn about specificity. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @AmitSchandillia I updated the answer. Now it will have higher specificity than the default border-radius.

Comment: Amit already has that same `ID` on the containing `<div>`... `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">`, if you are going to suggest this, have her remove the same ID from the <div>.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu I edited that part, didn't notice it at first.

Answer (score 22):

For Bootstrap 4 I did this in my style sheet:

```css
.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: #404040;
}
```

Comment: Had to change `border-radius` to `50%` to get them circular if anyone else does not have complete success with this solution.

Comment: It's the best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For `Bootstrap 5`, styling changed a little. I was able to achieve round indicators mixing SCSS variables with a css style:

This sets indicadors square, instead of rectanglular

```
$carousel-indicator-width: 10px;
$carousel-indicator-height: 10px;
```

This rounds the corners

```
.carousel .carousel-indicators button {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#myCarousel-indicators li{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}

.carousel-indicators li{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ol id="myCarousel-indicators" class="carousel-indicators"></ol>
```

Comment: It would be better if you can explain the code as well not just posting the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.glyphicon-chevron-right:before, .glyphicon-chevron-left:before {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5:

```
.carousel-indicators > button {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 12px !important;
    height: 12px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Exact circle please make sure that you have same width and height then it will give you the exact circle with border-radius: 50%;

```
.carousel-indicators li{
  border-radius:50%
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  background-color:#aaa;}
```

Comment: Bootstrap 5 does not use li for carousel indicators. Also if you try this styling the indicator is still not circular if you convert the current bootstrap 5 carousel indicator to li.