# How can I use rounded images in carousel bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am trying to use a bootstrap carousel with rounded images and I am unable to show only the rounded image. I have used overflow:hidden, unfortunately, it has not worked. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap carousel indicators are square; I want them round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464619/bootstrap-carousel-indicators-are-square-i-want-them-round)

Comment: have you tried `rounded-circle` class ?, also can you add your code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the overflow. add this class to rounded Image tag.

```
.carousel {
    border-radius: 55px 55px 55px 55px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```